# Picking which QNX partition to boot into automatically

Tags: operating-system, embedded, rtos, qnx

I currently have an embedded device with a flash card that has 3 QNX 6.5.0SP1 partitions - two bootable partitions (fs type 79), one data partition (fs type 78).  I would like to programmatically choose which of these two bootable partitions to boot into, based on a flag of some sort on the data partition (perhaps a `touch`'d file) set by user interaction before shutdown.  Is this possible? Ideally, the end result would have the chosen partition's file system mounted to root once booted.

I have tried modifying the `.boot` file, but I believe the partition has already been booted by the time execution is handed to `.boot`. I believe I need to modify the IPL, but I'm unsure how to read from any file system during the IPL.

Comment: What sort of processor is your board?  The IPL is responsible for loading and executing a .boot image (aka "image startup program").  The startup program is in turn responsible for choosing what filesystem to mount as root.

For x86 BIOS based systems, the QNX IPLs (there are two stages) respect the 'boot' partition flag.   The default boot process (diskboot) selects the root partition.  See ["Controlling How Neutrino Starts"](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_user_guide%2Fstarting.html&cp=13_11_8)

Comment: The processor is x86. The goal is to get the default boot process (I assume the .boot file) to pick a root partition based on the presence of some flag, or to pick a different boot process that would select a different root partition. @WillMiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to mark the "active" bootable partion by ensuring it's the only one with a `.diskroot` file that instructs [`diskboot`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/index.html#./com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/d/diskboot.html) to mount it as `/`.  The switching process would be: use [`fdisk boot`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/index.html#./com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/f/fdisk.html#Commands) to mark the new root partition as bootable; then `mv /.diskroot` to it.

If it is a strict requirement that the bootable partitions are not writable, you'll need to design a replacement boot script for your system that starts up the key drivers and does its own mounting, as `diskboot` does not support complex mounting behaviour (it does not support duplicate .diskroot mount points).  Your updated script can be linked in to a replacment for the `.boot` file using [mkifs](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/index.html#./com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/m/mkifs.html).

Key reference documentation:

- [Controlling How Neutrino Starts](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/index.html#./com.qnx.doc.neutrino_user_guide/starting.html)
- [Making an OS Image](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/index.html#./com.qnx.doc.neutrino_building/building_nto.html)
- [Sample Buildfiles](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/index.html#./com.qnx.doc.neutrino_building/config.html)

Finally, as a leg up, I can offer this shell script "fsscan" my company used to use for this purpose back in the QNX 6.3 days.  This script looks for a partition with a ".bootkey" file that matches a "bootkey" file included in the IFS; the contents of this file were a short version and date stamp.  This let us select a boot partition with nothing but `fdisk boot`, and it would find and mount the matching root partition.

```bash
#/proc/boot/sh

# fsscan for QNX - scans for and mounts filesystems
# includes analysis of .diskroot for QNX filesystems for use at boot.

# Options
do_mount=0
build_fstab=1
parse_diskroot=0
commit_string=""
keyfile="/proc/boot/bootkey"

## Parse commandline
while getopts "mndck:" opt ; do
    case $opt in
        m)
            do_mount=1
        ;;
        n)
            build_fstab=0
        ;;
        d)
            parse_diskroot=1
        ;;
        k)
            keyfile="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        c)
            commit_string="commit=none"
        ;;
    esac
done

if [ -r "$keyfile" ]; then
    keydata=`cat $keyfile`
else
    keyfile=""
fi    


echo "Scanning available disk partitions..."

if [ "$build_fstab" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "# fstab build by fsscan on `date`" > /etc/fstab
fi

# Get QNX devices
# We use two passes to figure out what to do.  First pass pre-mounts devices 
# and locates .bootkey, second pass manages other .diskroots.


UD=`ls /dev/ud*t79 /dev/ud*t78 /dev/ud*t77 2>/dev/null`
HD=`ls /dev/hd*t79 /dev/hd*t78 /dev/hd*t77 2>/dev/null`

QDEVS="$UD $HD"

# First pass
did_mount=""
was_mounted=""
for device in $QDEVS; do
    disk=`echo $device | sed -e "s/\/dev\/[hu]d\(.*\)t7[789]/\1/"`  
    type=`echo $device | sed -n -e "s/\/dev\/\([hu]\)d.*t7[789]/\1/p"`  
    id=`echo $device | sed -n -e "s/\/dev\/[hu]d.*t\(7[789]\)/\1/p"`    

    mountopts="rw"
    if [ ! -z "$commit_string" ]; then
        mountopts="$mountopts,$commit_string"
    fi
    
    # Check if already mounted
    mountpt=`df $device | awk "\\$1 == \"$device\" {print \\$6}"`

    is_mounted=0
    
    if [ -z "$mountpt" ]; then                
        num=$((80 - $id))
        mountpt="/fs/${type}d$disk-qnx4-$num"       
        
        if [ "$do_mount" -eq 1 ]; then 
            
            echo "Found QNX filesystem at $device, mounting as $mountpt"        
            mount -t qnx4 -o $mountopts $device $mountpt
            is_mounted=1
            did_mount="$did_mount $device"
        fi;
    
    else
        is_mounted=1        
        was_mounted="$was_mounted $device"        
        echo "Found QNX filesystem at $device already mounted as $mountpt"
    fi
    
    if [ "$is_mounted" -eq 1 ]; then         
        if [ -n "$keyfile" -a "$parse_diskroot" -eq 1 -a -r $mountpt/.diskroot -a -r $mountpt/.bootkey ]; then
            # Check boot key.
            fskeydata=`cat $mountpt/.bootkey`
            if [ "$keydata" = "$fskeydata" ]; then
                # Handle diskroot RIGHT NOW
                diskroot=`awk 'BEGIN { mp = "/" }
(NR == 1) && /\// { mp = $0; }
/^[ \t]*mount[ \t]*=/ { split($0,parts,/=/); mp = parts[2]; gsub(/^[ \t]*/,"",mp); gsub(/[ \t]*$/,"",mp);  }
END { print mp; }' <$mountpt/.diskroot`

#                   echo "$device: Diskroot mountpoint is '$diskroot'"                      
                
                if [ -z "$diskroot" ]; then             
                    diskroot="/"
                fi
                
                # Check for existing partition there
                if df $diskroot | awk "\$6 != \"$diskroot\" {exit 0} {exit 1}"; then
                    echo "Relocating QNX filesystem with matching key at $device to $diskroot"
                    umount $mountpt
                    if [ "$do_mount" -eq 1 ]; then
                        mount -t qnx4 -o $mountopts $device $diskroot
                    fi
                    mountpt="$diskroot"
                fi                            
            fi                
        fi;   
    else
            echo "Found QNX filesystem at $device, mountable as $mountpt"                       
    fi    
    
done;

#echo "Did mount: '$did_mount'   Was mounted: '$was_mounted'"

# Second pass
for device in $QDEVS; do
    disk=`echo $device | sed -e "s/\/dev\/[hu]d\(.*\)t7[789]/\1/"`  
    type=`echo $device | sed -n -e "s/\/dev\/\([hu]\)d.*t7[789]/\1/p"`  
    id=`echo $device | sed -n -e "s/\/dev\/[hu]d.*t\(7[789]\)/\1/p"`    

    mountopts="rw"
    if [ ! -z "$commit_string" ]; then
        mountopts="$mountopts,$commit_string"
    fi
    
    # Check if already mounted
    mountpt=`df $device | awk "\\$1 == \"$device\" {print \\$6}"`

    if echo $was_mounted | grep -q $device || echo $did_mount | grep -q $device; then
        # Process diskroot
        #echo "Considering $device for diskroot"
        # Read .diskroot
        if [ "$parse_diskroot" -eq 1 -a -r $mountpt/.diskroot ]; then
            diskroot=`awk 'BEGIN { mp = "/" }
(NR == 1) && /\// { mp = $0; }
/^[ \t]*mount[ \t]*=/ { split($0,parts,/=/); mp = parts[2]; gsub(/^[ \t]*/,"",mp); gsub(/[ \t]*$/,"",mp);  }
END { print mp; }' <$mountpt/.diskroot`

#           echo "$device: Diskroot mountpoint is '$diskroot'"                      
            
            if [ -z "$diskroot" ]; then             
                diskroot="/"
            fi
            
#           echo "Using '$diskroot' for $device"                    
                        
            # Check for existing partition there
            if df $diskroot | awk "\$6 != \"$diskroot\" {exit 0} {exit 1}"; then
                echo "Relocating QNX filesystem at $device to $diskroot"
                echo "umount $mountpt"
                umount $mountpt
                if [ "$do_mount" -eq 1 ]; then
                    echo "mount -t qnx4 -o $mountopts $device $diskroot"                
                    mount -t qnx4 -o $mountopts $device $diskroot
                fi
                mountpt="$diskroot"
            fi              
        fi                  
    else
        # Check is now mounted == bootkey
        if [ -z "$mountpt" ]; then                
            num=$((80 - $id))
            mountpt="/fs/${type}d$disk-qnx4-$num"
        fi
    fi

    if [ "$build_fstab" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "$device   $mountpt    qnx4    $mountopts  0   0" >> /etc/fstab
    fi;
done;                   



# Grab DOS devices.
lastdisk=""
for id in 1 4 6 11 12; do
    for device in `ls /dev/hd*t$id /dev/hd*t$id.* /dev/ud*t$id /dev/ud*t$id.* 2>/dev/null`; do
        disk=`echo $device | sed -e "s/\/dev\/\([hu]d.*\)t$id.*/\1/"`   

        # Check if already mounted
        mountpt=`df $device | awk "\\$1 == \"$device\" {print \\$6}"`
        mountopts="rw"

        
        if [ -z "$mountpt" ]; then                
            is_mounted=0
            
            # Find mountpoint
            if [ "X$lastdisk" != "X$disk" ]; then
                lastdisk="$disk"
                num=0
            fi
            
            while [ -z "$mountpt" ]; do
                num=$(($num + 1))
                mountpt="/fs/$disk-dos-$num"
                if [ -e "$mountpt" ]; then
                    mountpt=""
                fi
            done;

            if [ "$do_mount" -eq 1 ]; then
                echo "Found DOS filesystem at $device, mounting as $mountpt"
                mount -t dos -o $mountopts $device $mountpt
            else
                echo "Found DOS filesystem at $device, mountable as $mountpt"
            fi
                                
        else
            echo "Found DOS filesystem at $device, already mounted as $mountpt"        
        fi
        
        if [ "$build_fstab" -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "$device   $mountpt dos    $mountopts  0   0" >> /etc/fstab
        fi      
    done;
done;

    
echo "Partition scan complete."
```

NB: this script requires a full shell and some UNIX text processing utilities to be included in the .boot IFS.  QNX worked hard to keep their default IFS as small as possible; this wasn't a limitation for our application.

```
mount
umount
sleep
sh
awk
sed
ls
cat
echo
df
grep
```

Comment: Once the files are moved and the partition is made bootable, would you have to restart, since you've mounted other drives?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to reboot to remount /  -- I don't think it's possible to swap which partition is mounted as / on a booted system without some race conditions.  If changing the mounted root without rebooting is a hard requirement, I'd recommend not mounting them as / at all, and arranging all system paths to point to some logical name (/live maybe?) that is expected to be a process manager symlink to the active system root.